# Interferencia paginate laravel

Tags: laravel, paginación

Hola a todos pido disculpas si hago preguntas de forma seguida pero al resolver un problema  se me genero otro, estoy haciendo una página de lectura de libros y donde se pueden escuchar audio libros y todo esto lo hago en la misma página( en el **home.blade.php**), lo malo es que cuando hago un **paginate** me gustaría que solo avance en este caso lo que seleccione el usuario que por ejemplo si le da clic en la siguiente pagina de los libros de texto que solo avancen los libros de texto y que los audio libros se queden en la misma pagina en la que estaban, pero cuando le doy clic a la siguiente página como le agrega a la url:

```
?page=2
```

Entonces por ende avanzan ambas páginas, ¿hay alguna forma en la que solo avance o una o la otra? o ¿hay alguna mejor forma de hacer lo que estoy haciendo? Espero haberme dado a entender. Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: tienes 2 paginates diferente? una para la tabla de libros y otra para la de audios?

Comment: @HeynerMartinez si, los tengo separados

Comment: ok te ya te respondo lo que puedes hacer, lo que yo hago para casos asi

Comment: Recordé que hace un tiempo presente ese inconveniente, revise mis marcadores y aun lo tenia, te comparto el enlace de como user multiple pagination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086269/laravel-multiple-pagination-in-one-page espero te sea de ayuda a ti también

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logré resolver mi problema de acuerdo a lo que dice [la documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#multiple-paginator-instances-per-page), lo que es en lugar de hacer esto:

```
    $textBooks = Books::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    $audioBooks = Books::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Terminé haciendo esto:

```
    $textBooks = Books::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(
        $perPage = 3, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'textbooks'
    );
    $audioBooks = AudioBook::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(
        $perPage = 3, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'audiobooks'
    );
```